# How to change resolution with a script from ultrawide to "regular" resolution? (ex. 1440) on a MacBook Pro

Tags: display, applescript, resolution

I am using an UltraWide monitor while working from home. But when I'm screen sharing, it's a weird view for the others so I am hoping to find a quick way to change my resolution to black bars on the sides and give me a more 'normal' resolution.

Is there any app/script that can help me achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try [SwitchResX](https://www.madrau.com). I've used it for nearly the same use case as you, worked just fine for me.

Comment: When I use this app and change to something like 1080p, it just changes to a very stretched out blurry ultrawide screen instead of giving me black bars on the sides.

Answer (score 0):

I use both the **GUI** *application* [**Display Menu**](https://apps.apple.com/app/display-menu/id549083868?mt=12) and the *command line utility* [**displayplacer**](https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer), depending on my needs.

Both of these *applications* are currently *free*<sup>1</sup>.

**Display Menu** loads to the *menu bar* and is easily clicked, although I'd imagine the clicking could be automated using **AppleScript** if need be.

I use `displayplacer` in *shell scripts*.

<sup>1</sup> **Display Menu** has In-App Purchases: Display Menu Pro Upgrade

<sub>Note: I am not associated with the developers of the aforementioned *applications*, just a satisfied user.</sub>

Comment: When I use this app and change to something like 1080p, it just changes to a very stretched out blurry ultrawide screen instead of giving me black bars on the sides.